# How to debug Julia macros?

Tags: debugging, macros, julia, hygiene

*Note: This question refers to Julia v1.6. Of course, at any time the answers should ideally also answer the question for the most recent version.*

There seem to be a lot of questions and confusion about macro hygiene in Julia. While I read the manual pages in question, I still really struggle to write macros while using things like interpolation (`$name`), `quote` and other quoting syntax, the differences in behavior between macros and functions acting on expressions, `esc`, etc.

**What are the tools Julia provides for finding bugs in macros and how to use them effectively?**

This is certainly a broad question, which I think very much deserves a dedicated manual page, rather than the current afterthought in an overview of meta-programing. Nevertheless, I think it can be answered effectively (i.e., in a way that teaches me and others a lot about the main, general question) by considering and debugging a concrete example. Hence, I will discuss a simple

#### toy-example macro:

(Note that the macro `Base.@locals`
"Construct[s] a dictionary of the names (as symbols) and values of all local variables defined as of the call site" [from the docstring].)

```
# Julia 1.5
module MyModule

foo = "MyModule's foo"

macro mac(print_local=true)
    println("Dump of argument:{")
    dump(print_local)
    println("}\n\n")

    local_inmacro = "local in the macro"

    return quote
        println(repeat("-", 30)) # better readability of output

        # intention: use variable local to the macro to make a temporary variable in the user's scope
        # (can you think of a reason why one might want to do this?)
        var_inquote = $local_inmacro * "_modified"

        # intention: evaluate `print_local` in user scope 
        # (THIS CONTAINS AN ERROR ON PURPOSE!
        # One should write `if $(esc(print_local))` to achieve intention.)
        if $print_local
            # intention: get local variables in caller scope
            println("Local in caller scope: ", Base.@locals)
        else
            # intention: local to macro or module AA.
            println($foo)
            println($local_inmacro)
            println(var_inquote)
        end
    end
end

end  # module MyModule
```

#### Some code to test this

```
function testmacro()
    foo = "caller's foo"

    MyModule.@mac  # prints `Dict` containing "caller's foo"

    MyModule.@mac true # (Exactly the same)

    MyModule.@mac false # prints stuff local to `@mac` and `MyModule`

    # If a variable name is passed instead of `true` or `false`, 
    # it doesn't work. This is because of macro hygiene,
    # which renames and rescopes interpolated variables.
    # (Intended behaviour is achieved by proper escaping the variable in the macro)
    var_false = false
    MyModule.@mac var_false  # gives `UndefVarError`
end

testmacro()
```

#### Pretend that you don't understand why the error happens. How do we find out what's going on?

Debugging techniques (that I'm aware of) include:

- `@macroexpand (expr)` : expand all macros inside `(expr)`
- `@macroexpand1 (expr)` : expand only the outer-most macro in `(expr)`, usually just the macro you are debugging. Useful, e.g., if the macro you're debugging returns expressions with `@warn` inside, which you don't want to see expanded.
- `macroexpand(m::Module, x; recursive=true)` : combines the above two and allows to specify the "caller"-module
- `dump(arg)` : can be used inside a macro to inspect its argument `arg`.
- `eval(expr)` : to evaluate expressions (should almost never be used inside a macro body).

**Please help add useful things to this list.**

Using `dump` reveals that the argument `print_local` during the problematic (i.e. last) macro call is a `Symbol`, to be exact, it has the value `:var_false`.

Let's look at the expression that the macro returns. This can be done, e.g., by replacing the last macro call (`MyModule.@mac var_false`) by `return (@macroexpand1 MyModule.@mac var_false)`. Result:

```
quote
    #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:14 =#
    Main.MyModule.println(Main.MyModule.repeat("-", 30))
    #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:18 =#
    var"#5#var_inquote" = "local in the macro" * "_modified"
    #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:23 =#
    if Main.MyModule.var_false
        #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:25 =#
        Main.MyModule.println("Local in caller scope: ", #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:25 =# Base.@locals())
    else
        #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:28 =#
        Main.MyModule.println("MyModule's foo")
        #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:29 =#
        Main.MyModule.println("local in the macro")
        #= <CENSORED PATH>.jl:30 =#
        Main.MyModule.println(var"#5#var_inquote")
    end
end
```

We could manually remove the annoying comments (surely there is a built-in way to do that?).

In this simplistic example, the debugging tools listed here are enough to see the problem. We notice that the `if` statement in the macro's return expression "rescopes" the interpolated symbol to the macro's parent module: it looks at `Main.MyModule.var_false`. We intended for it to be `Main.var_false` in the caller scope.

One can solve this problem by replacing `if $print_local` by `if $(esc(print_local))`. In that case, macro hygiene will leave the contents of the `print_local` variable alone. I am still a bit confused as to the order and placement of `esc` and `$` for interpolation into expressions.

Suppose that we mess up and write `if $esc(print_local)` instead, thus interpolating the `esc` function into the expression, rather than escaping anything (similar mistakes have cost me quite a bit of headache). This results in the returned expression (obtained via `@macroexpand1`) being impossible to execute via `eval`, since the `esc` function is weird outside of a macro, returning in stuff like`:($(Expr(:escape, <somthing>)))`. In fact, I am generally confused as to when `Expr`essions obtained via `@macroexpand` are actually executable (to the same effect as the macro call) and how to execute them (`eval` doesn't always do the trick). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is a good question, I'm surprised it hasn't generated replies, you may want to 1. start a discussion at https://discourse.julialang.org/, 2. extract one or two specific questions from the above and repost them in separate threads here after deleting this one (please do not cross-post).